# Are there any heuristic client fetching strategies/algorithms/theory in CRM WebApplications (call center)

Tags: algorithm, web-applications, crm

I am creating a ASP .NET MVC CRM for my company to be(not yet exists). We are going to call some people from our database(no phone spam or similar). We got a fullfiled database of people, about 2000 for starters it will grow up to 10 000. When I had doubtfull pleasure talking to my thesis promoter he mentioned "client feeding/fetching" techniques used in CRM but he did not want to elaborate on it.

There are going to be 3 employees calling those people. After the call they wil have to set status for every call: `1st attempt no answer`, `2nd attempt no answer`, `call later`, `do not call`.

Whenever they click `next` button app suppose to fetch them next person from `db` but do not forget about those who have status: `call later`. At least when I was working as tele marketer it worked this way.

**Question:** Are there any strategies/algorithms in fetching those people based on history? Creating temporary `Collections` with people I should call later and interlace them with those I did not call? Or maybe there are much better statuses values than those I proposed?

The question seems broad but I do not see any other stack exchange forum where users would know anything about it, if I am wrong please write a comment **I will move the question immediately**.

Comment: This sort of question seems to get downvoted because it doesn't pertain to specific technical issues and has no definitive solution.  However I think it is a good question and I am also interested in the answers/discussion.